# How to copy cross-compiled Qt binaries from one computer to another

Tags: qt5, beagleboneblack

So on my current laptop has cross compiled binaries for Qt5.13 with Beaglebone Black as target device. At my workplace, we want to have the ability of working on any desktop or laptop on same target to make different components of our Qt project. Normally as per my knowledge and after seeing some github repos that share precompiled Raspberry Pi binaries, I copied the folder containing qmake and other files in *hostprefix* directory to another computer but Qt creator on that computer says the qmake is not executable. I also have the toolchain I used on one machine copied to another.

Is this some kind PATH related issue or copying the binaries doesn't work at all? Because cross compiling is a pain in the ass especially with a platform like Beaglebone black.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this explanation: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deployment-embedded-linux.html

It's possible in Qt Creator to deploy your binaries to a target platform. You just need to setup everything. Then you will be able to compile, deploy and debug remotely.